# Getting latest of many results only grouped by user in DB2/400

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm posting my query and results, but I'm trying to simply get this limited to only the latest status and timestamp by creator.

```
    select t2.creator, t1.event_id, t2.status, max(t2.createdTS)
    from schema.event T1
    inner join schema.event_to_event_statust T2
    on t1.event_id = t2.event_id
    group by t2.creator, t1.event_id, t2.status;



    creator     |   event_id    |   status  | createdTS
    -----------------------------------------------------
    123                 1           New         2019-01-29 17:27:50.899408
    123                 1           Live        2019-01-29 17:29:50.899408
    123                 1           Closed      2019-01-29 17:45:50.899408
    456                 5           New         2019-01-29 17:32:50.899408
    456                 5           Live        2019-01-29 17:48:50.899408
```

My desired results for this set would actually be

```
    creator     |   event_id    |   status  | createdTS
    -----------------------------------------------------
    123                 1           Closed      2019-01-29 17:45:50.899408
    456                 5           Live        2019-01-29 17:48:50.899408
```

So I should only have one row per creator and it should be the latest record. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, not really a huge fan of having my question downvoted with no comment/explanation, but whatever.

Comment: Is the join really needed?

Comment: Yes,  it's the only way I can get the status of the user

Comment: status is selected from t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work "as is" on your IBM i?

```
WITH RES (creator, event_id, status, createdTS) AS 
(
VALUES
  (123, 1, 'New',    TIMESTAMP('2019-01-29 17:27:50.899408'))
, (123, 1, 'Live',   TIMESTAMP('2019-01-29 17:29:50.899408'))
, (123, 1, 'Closed', TIMESTAMP('2019-01-29 17:45:50.899408'))
, (456, 5, 'New',    TIMESTAMP('2019-01-29 17:32:50.899408'))
, (456, 5, 'Live',   TIMESTAMP('2019-01-29 17:48:50.899408'))
)
SELECT creator, event_id, status, createdTS
FROM 
(
SELECT creator, event_id, status, createdTS
, ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY creator ORDER BY createdTS desc) AS rn
FROM RES
) T
WHERE RN=1;
```

If not, then what's your IBM i version and modification?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with temp as (
 select t2.creator, t1.event_id, t2.status, t2.createdTS
        row_number() over (partition by t2.creator order by t2.createdTS desc) as rownum
    from schema.event T1
    inner join schema.event_to_event_statust T2
    on t1.event_id = t2.event_id
    group by t2.creator, t1.event_id, t2.status
)
select creator, event_id, status, createdTS
  from temp
 where rownum = 1
```

@MarkBarinstein: Thanks SQL corrected

an alternative might be

```
select t2.creator, t1.event_id, t2.status, t2.createdTS
    from event T1
    inner join event_to_event_status T2
    on t1.event_id = t2.event_id
 INNER JOIN (select event_id, creator, max(createdts) AS createdts
              FROM  event_to_event_status
              GROUP BY event_id, creator) AS x
              ON t2.event_id = x.event_id AND t2.creator = x.creator AND t2.createdts = x.createdts
```

I do not have a iSeries to try it sorry

Comment: Ok so I had to fix it to use row_number for my version of db2 with iseries 7 but I still get that ```Token PARTITION was not valid, valid tokens:)```